# Yii notify user about constraint violation

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm using Yii, and I want to notify the user about a constraint violation when saving in database. But the way I proceed does not  fix the problem. 
This my code.

***The action :***

```
public function actionPublierAContact($id){
    $model = new PublierAContact;
    if(isset($_POST['PublierAContact'])){
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['PublierAContact']);
        try{
            $model->save();
        }catch(CException $e){
            Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('publierac', 'alert("Deja publié")');
        }
        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $id));
    }
    $this->render('publieracontact', array('model'=> $model, 'id' => $id));
}
```

But, with this, I cannot see the `alert` box in the browser. 
Can somebody help me fix it quickly ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of catching an exception, build your constraint check as a validation. It then makes it far easier to display model errors on your form.

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor change of your codes. Try by changing `$model->setAttributes( $_POST['PublierAContact'] );` to `$model->setAttributes = $_POST['PublierAContact'];` and `redirect` instance after saving. Can try like below...

```
public function actionPublierAContact($id){
    $model = new PublierAContact;
    if(isset($_POST['PublierAContact'])){
        $model->setAttributes = $_POST['PublierAContact'];
        try{
            if($model->save()){
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $id));
            }
        }catch(CException $ex){
            Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('publierac', 'alert("Deja publié")');
        }
    }
    $this->render('publieracontact', array('model'=> $model, 'id' => $id));
}
```